# Run a sequence after another sequence with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating an MapboxGL map that needs to support lots of interactivity via buttons and sliders.

MapboxGL map instances are *stateful* and have *temperamental lifecycles* due to lots of async fetching of tiles and sources. This means most of the work is done inside event handlers. This makes me think that RxJS is a solid candidate for managing all of this interactivity.

For example, if you want to add a feature layer to a map, [the mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/) suggest doing everything in a `map.on('load', handler)`. That's fine for static maps, but it's a hassle to coordinate imperative event handlers for a map that will have 20+ toggles/sliders/controls.

What I want to do is create sequences for each individual operation. The most basic of which is **loading the map then adding the base feature layer after the map loads**.

So here's what I've got, I've been using RxJS for about 5 hours total, so maybe there is something I just don't know that I don't know.

**Snippet:**

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
      center: [-122.78, 38.43],
      zoom: 10
  });

  // Check every 100ms if the map is loaded, if so emit
  var loaded$ = Rx.Observable
    .interval(100)
    .map(() => map.loaded())
    .filter(x => x)
    .first();

  // We must wait until the map is loaded before attaching the feature layer.
  var addLayer = loaded$.subscribe(
    baseMapLoaded, errorHandler, addFeatureLayerAndSource
  );

  // Attaching the feature layer sets the map.loaded() to false
  // while it fetches the tiles.
  // 
  // When the feature layer and source are loaded,
  // log 'all tiles loaded' then 'completed' to the console
  //
  // Why can I declare `addLayer` and `completed` like this?
  // Shouldn't these both fire after the loaded$ emits the first time,
  // causing an error?
  var completed = loaded$.subscribe(tilesLoaded, errorHandler, completeHandler);

  /* Misc Handlers */
  function addFeatureLayerAndSource() {
    console.log(2, 'adding feature layer and source');
    map.addSource('parcel_data', {
      'type': 'vector',
      'tiles': ['http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}']
    });

    map.addLayer({
      "id": "parcel_data",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "parcel_data",
      "source-layer": "parcel_data",
    });
  }
  function baseMapLoaded() { console.log(1, 'base map loaded'); }
  function tilesLoaded() { console.log(3, 'all tiles loaded'); }
  function errorHandler(err) { console.log('error handling', err); }
  function completeHandler() { console.log('completed'); }
```

**EDIT: Updated the snippet to reflect @CalvinBeldin's help. Currently trying to figure out why this actually works. The order of my console.logs is correct:**

```
1 "base map loaded"
2 "adding feature layer and source"
3 "all tiles loaded"
completed
```

Answer (score 3):

The Observable returned by `renderObservable.last()` is never going to fire because `renderObservable`'s complete event never occurs (`renderObservable` will just keep listening for `render` events until it's disposed, so in this sense it never "completes").

You'll need to create a new Observable that emits when the last render occurs. Per limitations with the MapboxGL API, a polling solution might be the only way to go:

```
// Emits the value of map.loaded() every 100ms; you can update this
// time interval to better suit your needs, or get super fancy
// and implement a different polling strategy.
const loaded$ = Rx.Observable.interval(100).map(() => map.loaded());

// Will emit once map.loaded() is true.
const isLoaded$ = loaded$.filter(x => x).first();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! According to  the MapboxGL issue tracker, the only way to know when the last render event has fired is to check if `map.loaded() === true` from within the 'render' event handler. This is why I was using `.last()` with the predicate function. Because of this cludginess, I'm hoping to establish an easy way to subscribe to the last of the render events being fired so that I can reuse it in multiple places.

Comment: You could set up an Observable that simply polls the map every so often, filter on if loaded is true, then emit. Will update answer with code soon.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to see that.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my initial question with my new code. Any idea why I can declare two `loaded$.first()`s and have them execute synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

I might not completely understood what is the problem.
The main points:

- Keep the load event to the observers that subscribed after load event already happned ((Behavior|Replay)Subject)
- Return render events only after render event occurred (flatMap)

---

```
loadSource$ = Observable.fromEvent(map, 'load').first();

// You need load$ to be a BehaviorSubject or replay last value on
// In order to keep state of wheter laod event happend or not
// For observers which subscribed after load event already happened
load$ = loadSource.replay(1);
render$ = Observable.fromEvent(map, 'render');
renderAfterLoad$ = load$.flatMap(() => render$);

load$.subscribe(() => {
  map.addSource('source_data', {
    'type': 'vector',
    'tiles': ['http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}']
  });

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "layer_data",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "source_data",
    "source-layer": "source_layer_id",
  });
});

render$.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('all tiles loaded');
});
```